# Laravel related model attributes are empty?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to give ability on user to see his orders. I have created relationships but when i (dd) the result of the function, the related model attributes are empty.

I don't know what is wrong.

Here is my buyer function

//Buyer Orders

```
 public function myOrders()
 { 
 $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id); 
 $user = $user->products();
 dd($user);// related model attributes shows empty

 return view('myOrders')->with(compact('user'));

 }
```

and here is my user

```
 public function products()
 {
  return $this->hasMany(Products_model::class);
 }

 public function orders()
 {
 return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
 }

public function allOrdersBuyerSeller() 
{ 
return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class); 
}
```

products_model

```
 public function orders() 
 {
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product');
 }

 public function user() 
 {
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
```

User Migration

```
  */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
```

Product Migration

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('pro_name');
        $table->integer('pro_price');
        $table->text('pro_info');
        $table->integer('stock');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->bigInteger('seller_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
   }
```

I would like to see the attributes of the table like price, name, info, img and etc.

Comment: Sidenote, `User::find(auth()->user()->id)` is redundant; `auth()->user()` is likely going to contain the same thing, and is just an extra DB query. `Products_model` should also just be `Product`; be consistent with naming. That also may be causing problems with your relationship. Can you include your migration for Users and Products?

Comment: what should I use? @TimLewis

Comment: `auth()->user()->products`, or `auth()->user()->products()->get()`.

Comment: I have Updated the question with product and user migration@TimLewis

Comment: Your code is all over the place... Why is your `myOrders()` function returning `Product`s?

Comment: I just wanted to get the orders data including product details

Comment: Then you likely need to call `$user->orders`, loop those orders and display the products attached to each individual order.

Comment: If I dd($products) ->it shows empty array and if I dd($user) it shows user information only@TimLewis

Answer (score 1):

Barring the comments about your code, the reason you're not seeing the result of your `products` query is that you're not passing a closure to the query.

```
$user = $user->products();
```

Currently, `$user` is a `QueryBuilder` instance. Until you use a `closure`, like `first()`, `get()`, `paginate()`, etc, you won't be able to see the rows. Modify your code to the following:

```
$products = $user->products;
// OR
$products = $user->products()->get();
```

If you omit the `()`, it will load the relationship using `products()->get()`, unless already loaded.

Edit: You likely need to include foreign keys to your relationships as the Model name won't match:

User.php

```
public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany(Product_model::class, "seller_id", "id");
}
```

Probably best to review the contents of the documentation for Relationships; https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships. There's a lot of incorrect practices going on with your naming, querying, etc.

Comment: it is just showing empty array like this `Collection {#293 ▼
  #items: []
}`